# I'm having an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm creating an app directory for web scraping which is scrape inside my django_project. I'm having an an error in importing a class from my models.py module into my views.py module.

this is my project structure:

[image]

[image]

Here's my code inside models.py in scrape app

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

# model -- headline (title, url, date)

    class Headline(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        url = models.TextField()
        event_date = models.TextField()

            def __str__(self):
                return self.title
```

and this code inside views.py in scrape app

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from .models import Headline

# Create your views here.
def scrape():
    # Use the session to get the URL
    session = requests.Session()
    url = 'https://allevents.in/malacca/all?ref=cityhome-popular'
    # Content is basically grabs all the HTML that comes from the session
    content = session.get(url, verify=False).content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    # Return a list
    #item = soup.find_all('div', class_="event-item")
    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_="event-item"):
        title = item.find("h3").text.strip()
        linkhref = item.find("h3").find("a").get('href')
        date_posted = item.find("div", {"class":"right"})

        new_headline = Headline()
        new_headline.title = title
        new_headline.url = linkhref
        new_headline.event_date = date_posted
        new_headline.save()

    return redirect('/event/')
```

after try run python views.py from cmd this error is appeared

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import Headline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I also try this in my views.py

```
from scrape.models import Headline
```

but I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from scrape.models import Headline
  File "C:\Users\USER\django_project\scrape\scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Headline
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

also if i change from models import Headline

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import Headline
  File "C:\Users\USER\django_project\scrape\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Headline(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the `views.py` file by itself? Please go through [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) to actually learn how you're supposed to run a django app. You need to run the development server and Django will execute the appropriate code automatically.

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: @Stevy i ady edited my post.

Comment: @Kerberos, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to import your `model` you should use the path to, in this case, `models.py` to specificy where Python should look. Then you can import one or multiple models by specifying their class names like this:

`from <path_to_models.py> import <your_model_name>`

To solve your problem, change:

`from .models import Headline`

to

`from models import Headline`

In all your files where you are importing your `Headline` model

**EDIT**

When you are using an IDE that has autofill, Pycharm for example. You can import the model in an easy way:

1. Make sure the imported model is used in your file
2. Remove the import line
3. Put your cursor at the end of the model you want to import in the file
4. Press `alt + enter`
5. Click on `import model`

Comment: it shows new erro:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrape.models import Headline
  File "C:\Users\USER\django_project\scrape\scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Headline
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: it shows

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scrape.models import Headline
  File "C:\Users\USER\django_project\scrape\scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scrape.models import Headline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrape.models'; 'scrape' is not a package

Comment: The import issue is solved. How are you running your Django app? You should use the `manage.py` command. You can read about setting up and running a Django app correctly in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

```
testapp
   models.py
   serializers.py
```

serializers.py :

```
   from .models import Product
```

> This worked for me.